# Xamarin forms touch manipulation HitTest always returns fasle

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, geometry, skiasharp

Am drawing a bitmap of width 85 and height 85 on SKCanvas @ X=149, Y=270 point. But the Hitest as follows always returns false! while debugging the height value of rect is replaced to some negative value!

```
location = new SKpoint(149,270);
SKRect rect = new SKRect(149, 270, 85,85);
return rect.Contains(location);
```

Need to get enlighten on anything am doing wrong here.Also, how a SKRect is formed given a point and width and Height?

Comment: You need to set the matrix to the identity matrix first and then, as you can see in the docs here
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/transforms/touch , perform rect = matrix.MapRect(rect); before your return statement to apply the matrix to the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

as I pointed out in your previous question, the constructor for [SKRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp.skrect.-ctor?view=skiasharp-1.68.1#SkiaSharp_SKRect__ctor_System_Single_System_Single_System_Single_System_Single_) is

```
public SKRect (float left, float top, float right, float bottom);
```

so you need to pass it the coordinates of the TOP LEFT and BOTTOM RIGHT point, not the WIDTH and HEIGHT

Comment: sure, am checking on it. between i encountered another problem. what is the best way  to replace an existing bitmap and force redraw a canvas? Along with touch effect!